# Trying to upload a newer version of my application. App name does not show up while Archiving.

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, app-store

I am trying to upload a newer version to app store, I have done all the steps as described in the Docs. However when I archive and try to submit app for upload I cannot see my app under "Choose an application record and profile to sign with. It shows my other two apps under Application, however provisioning profile is correct. below is the screen shot explaining the issue. [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you've selected the "Ready to Upload Binary" button for this version in ITC?

Comment: Yes I have done that, actually my previous (update) version was rejected, I am a beginner in this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I remember correctly, but you may have to go back in and do this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first go to [itunesconnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and submit details there for new version. and try again after feel details.

Comment: The details are already done, my version was rejected and I am trying to upload a newer one.

Comment: Currently Your app is showing "Ready To upload". or not